# request.allHTTPHeaderFields returns always Optional([:])

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to get the last modified date of a webpage and tried following code. But it always returns "Optional([:])" (empty) in the console:

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.carl-bechstein-gymnasium.de/news/news_index.htm")

let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
req.httpMethod = "GET"
let headerFields = req.allHTTPHeaderFields
print(headerFields)
```

I also added this page to the Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://www.carl-bechstein-gymnasium.de/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But it did not work.

So I tried to check, if there are any headers and there are! Here an excerpt from the [website](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html), where I checked it:

> Date:·Thu,·26·Oct·2017·20:15:42·GMT(CR)(LF)
>   Content-Type:·text/html(CR)(LF)
>   Content-Length:·36519(CR)(LF)
>   Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
>   Server:·Apache(CR)(LF)
>   Last-Modified:·Wed,·18·Oct·2017·15:17:42·GMT(CR)(LF)

Now I am totally confused and hope for help soon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to get the headers for the request or response to the website? Right now you're getting all the headers for the request, and since you don't have any, it'll be empty.

If you're trying to get the response headers, you can get those through the `URLResponse` by casting it to a `HTTPURLResponse` object returned in a `URLSession` data task, like so:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, response, error in
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(httpResponse.allHeaderFields)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I must have been blind... XD

Answer (score 4):

`req.allHTTPHeaderFields` is the headers for your request, not the headers for the response.  You haven't actually sent the request in this code, you've only configured one to send.

Comment: Beat me to it by 20 seconds!